# SASS multiple file output

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to output multiple css files from one scss file?

Example:

I have default.sass, but I also want to create an unminified default.css and minified default.min.css.

I know I could do this with two command prompts open, but I was hoping I could knock it out with command.

Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking too; unfortunately, I'm gonna have to roll my own `@export { }` at-rule. Given `@export "foo" { }` that block writes to `foo.css`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution of sorts for this if you're using Windows, although it's a bit ungainly.

Make 3 batch files, all in the same folder. The first will be the file you actually run, the other two are programs that it will run, suppressed, with the `START` command.

```
@echo off
START "Regular CSS" /D%~dp0 /B "core.css.bat"
START "Minified CSS" /D%~dp0 /B "core.min.css.bat"
```

"* CSS" will be the window title. Necessary, but unused in this case. "/D%~dp0" sets the working directory to the execution directory. "/B" suppresses new window creation and runs it in the current console instead. "*.bat" are the batch files to run.

The second would be your normal CSS file.

```
@echo off
sass --watch ./core.scss:../css/core.css --style expanded --cache-location ./.core.css-cache
```

The third, your minified CSS.

```
@echo off
sass --watch ./core.scss:../css/core.min.css --style compressed --cache-location ./.core.min.css-cache
```

You *must* specify separate cache locations, otherwise the compiler will explode.

Because `START` does not wait for execution termination unless flagged with `/WAIT`, this will spin off both batch files at once inside one console. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will also prompt you to kill both sessions individually.

Feel free to play with the details, obviously, but this general concept is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by jetbrain. It's simple to have multiple output with different style. Just add other file watcher by different argument.

For standard output at argument input:

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:css\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css --style expanded
```

And for minify output at argument input:

```
--no-cache --update $FileName$:css\$FileNameWithoutExtension$-min.css --style compressed
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, running on Windows. The easiest way for me to solve it was to open two command prompts. With with `style=compressed` and the other with `style=expanded`. Not the most comfortable solution, but it is the easiest one.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to have multiple consoles open.